# ¿Cuál es el nombre de la pantalla de carga en aplicaciones?

Tags: aplicación-web, layout, aplicación-escritorio

No se si se hacen llamar así, lo que quiero hacer es lo que está en la imagen que pertenece a una aplicación llamada Discord que está hecha en JavaScript, Elixir y Electron.

¿Cuál es su nombre técnico de tal forma que me ayude en mis esfuerzos de búsqueda e investigación dirigidos a hacer algo similar?

[image: "Ventana de carga o Starting" de Discord]

Comment: a modo general sin ningún lenguaje, yo las conozco cuando las usé en .NET como splash screen

Comment: Bienvenido. Este sitio es algo diferente a otros en el que la intención es que los hilos de pregunta-respuesta sea material de referencia así hay que evitar usos de medios preponderantemente sociales como lo son los saludos y despedidas y se debe incluir en el cuerpo de la pregunta directamente la consulta. Por lo anterior, voy a editar tu pregunta. Mientras tanto te sugiero seguir el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: @Alfredo te lo agradezco mucho, con ese nombre ya encontré mucha mas información del tema. Ya llevaba 2 horas buscando sin resultados.

Comment: @Rubén tendré en cuenta tu sugerencia. Hasta ahora había encontrado todo lo que necesitaba sin necesidad de preguntar, así que soy nuevo en la plataforma.

Comment: Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación en el ámbito definido en el [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como mencionó Alfredo en un comentario, el término es [splash screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splash_screen). Me parece que es el mismo que se usa en español ya que no hay una traducción oficial del artículo original en inglés al español, aunque algunas páginas que se ofrecen en inglés y español como https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/ usan como traducción "pantalla de presentación".

Comment: No todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que no tratan sobre la programación o el desarrollo como lo definimos en el Centro de ayuda. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Entiendo de donde viene tu comentario, pero no estoy de acuerdo, en particular porque no veo a qué frustración te refieres. No me sentiría frustrado si se cierra esta pregunta. Quizás luego vaya a [Meta] a revivir alguna discusión relacionada o crear una nueva.

Comment: A mí tampoco me termina de convencer como suena (es una copia literal de [answer]), quizás podría plantearse reescribirla de alguna manera. La frustración para el que responde puede venir en forma de votos negativos (sabes cómo vota alguna gente) o comentarios de algún moderador pesado. La idea es la misma: no se debería responder a preguntas que no se ajustan bien a los estándares del sitio.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sí, a eso me refería con entender de donde viene :D Si bien la no es perfecta, me parece que esta pregunta sí está dentro del alcance del sitio, y por ello la respondí, particularmente porque uno no debe responder en comentarios :)